# Android TabActivity NullPointerException

Tags: android, tabactivity

Problems with the TabActivity...

I get this Exception

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:1651)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:656)
    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:326)
    at android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:216)
    at home.android.yahtzee.activities.GameActivity.onCreate(GameActivity.java:36)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1780)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1837)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:132)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1033)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:143)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4196)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

with this code

```
public class GameActivity extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.tab_handler);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        Player player = WhoIsPlayingDialog.playerSelected;
        Resources res = getResources(); // Resource object to get Drawables
        TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
        tabHost.setup();
        tabHost.setTag(this);
        TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(player.getName());
        Intent intent = new Intent(GameActivity.this, GamePlayerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("player", gson.toJson(player));
        spec.setContent(intent);
        spec.setIndicator(player.getName(), res.getDrawable(player.getDroid()));
        tabHost.addTab(spec); <============ Line 36.
    }
}
```

And I do not know why. Can anyone tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you do not need to call `tabHost.setup()` when you have already called getTabHost().

Second, you likely get NullPointerException because either `res.getDrawable(player.getDroid())` or `player.getName()` returns null.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will remove the `tabHost.setup()`. I have checked and `res.getDrawable(player.getDroid())` `player.getName()` are not null.

Comment: Did you specified your TabHost with `android:id="@+android:id/tabhost"` in your layout file?
Did you declare `GamePlayerActivity.class` in manifest file?

Comment: Try using `getApplicationContext()` as first argument passed to Intent constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try to use it like:

```
...    
TabHost.TabSpec spec;
Intent intent; 

intent = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), GamePlayerActivity.class);
spec = tabHost.newTabSpec(player.getName()).setIndicator(player.getName(),res.getDrawable(player.getDroid())).setContent(intent); 
tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and remove `tabHost.setup();`

Answer (score 0):

Error is at line `GameActivity.java:36` , no line number here . 
check what is null in this line .
at a broad level i think  P`layer player = WhoIsPlayingDialog.playerSelected;` might be null if u did not initialize static `playerSelected`

Comment: Sorry. I have added the line number. the `player` is not null as it has been initialized.